# NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 for AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

AVAudioPlayer has been giving me the following error on some local MP3 files:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "(null)"
```

I'm downloading a zip file to the Documents directory, then unzipping using a library called [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive).

In the Documents directory, a folder is created to contain the unzipped files.

I was able to play entire albums without any issues.
Everything was going fine until I start downloading certain files.

I've looked for similar questions (osx), possibly stating that this is a permission error, but I haven't managed to make it work.

Does anyone know what this error is?
It seems to not be on any documentation either.

Ex.

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var docDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

func showContentsOfSubDirectories() {
    do {
        let files = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docDirectory)
        print("----")
        for file in files {
            print("> \(file)")
            do {
                var rsrc: AnyObject?
                let possibleDir = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docDirectory + "/" + file)
                try possibleDir.getResourceValue(&rsrc, forKey: NSURLIsDirectoryKey)
                if let isDirectory = rsrc as? NSNumber {
                    if Bool(isDirectory) {
                        let subFiles = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(docDirectory + "/" + file)
                        for subFile in subFiles {
                            print("  >> \(subFile)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        print("----")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I use the above code for checking the directory.
This would give me in debugging:

> ALBUM NAME
>
> > SONG1.mp3
> >
> > SONG2.mp3
> >
> > SONG3.mp3
> >
> > SONG4.mp3

So it exists.

```
let filePath = docDirectory + "/" + ALBUM_NAME + "/SONG1.mp3"
//  ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXX/data/Containers/Data/Application/XXX/ 
// Same issue happens on actual device too

do {
    try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!))
} catch let error as NSError {
}
```

This works on some and doesn't on others.

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma Thanks, I was about to edit it.

Comment: What I did was use the NSFileManager to set 0777 permission to every file that was unzipped. That seemed to increase the chance of being able to play files.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same error and I can confirm that it was (at least, in my case) a permissions error. Specifically, related to the `NSFileProtectionKey`.

Setting `NSFileProtectionKey` to `NSFileProtectionNone` solves it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail how to do that? Or if any code needs to be written, can you edit your answer to show some code please?

Comment: @C0D3 it will be something like `let attrs = [.protectionKey : .none]; FileManager.default.setAttributes(attrs, ofItemAtPath: path)`